# Finding difficulty in understanding basic additions in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I'm trying to work on some basic concepts. I tried addition logic in a more random way where I thought I'll get errors. But out of surpize I'm getting output. For example, a++++++++++++++++++ 1 is giving output. So, can any explain what exactly kind of additions are being performed here. Please find the code which I tried.

```
>>> a++ + 1
4
>>> ++a + 1
4
>>> a++ ++ 1
4
>>> ++a ++ 1
4
>>> a++ +++ 1
4
>>> ++a +++ 1
4
>>> a+++ 1
4
>>> a++++++++ sdjfksdopfjsopdfjsd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#112>", line 1, in <module>
    a++++++++ sdjfksdopfjsopdfjsd
NameError: name 'sdjfksdopfjsopdfjsd' is not defined
>>> a++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a++++
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a+++
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a++
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 1
4
>>> a++ 1
4
>>> a++ + 1
4
>>> ++a
3
```

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a single specific question?

Comment: `++2` == `+2`, etc.

Comment: specifically `+++5` == `+(++5)` == `++5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` in most of your cases there is simply the unary `+` operator, not the addition operator or increment operator (the latter of which doesn't exist in Python).

I.e. `++1` is `+(+1)`, which doesn't really do anything. In contrast, the unary `-` operator does something: `-1` is `-1`, `--1` is `1`, `---1` is `-1`.

All the operations that are valid in your example boil down to `a + 1` if you remove the redundant `+` operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `+` and `-` operators in a row, because they don't represent add/subtract, but rather the positive/negative *sign* of a number. For example,

```
a + +1
```

is adding `a` and `+1` together. The spaces don't matter here, so these are all equilevant:

```
a + +1
a++1
a + + 1
a+ +1
a++ 1
a        +            +          1
```

Now, because adding a sign to a number (e.g. `+5` or `-5`) still keeps it as a number, you can reapply another sign to the new number. And another. And another. To infinity.

The negative sign actually changes the number's sign, just like in maths:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> -x
-5
>>> -(-5)
5
>>> --5  # Unlike maths, we don't need parenthesis
5
>>> -----5
-5
```

You can do this exact thing with `+`, it's just that it doesn't do anything:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> +x
5
>>> ++++x
5
>>> +++++++++++++++++1
1
```

And now take this number, `+++++++++++++++++1`, and append it to `3`:

```
>>> 3 + +++++++++++++++++1
4
```

As you see, there's only one addition operation, and the rest are just *unary* operators to indicate the sign of the number.